# can't read app.config file from c# project

Tags: c#, app-config

I'm trying to read some keys from the app.config file. Even though I'm using `System.Configuration` the keys cannot be read.

reading the value:

```
private static readonly string vals = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["vals"];
```

value in the app.config:

```
<add key="vals" value="1,2,5" />
```

using the value via `Console.WriteLine(vals);` returns an `System.TypeInitializationException`.

I've am working on another projects and using the app.config keys the same way. It's working there.

File Structure:

```
- Project
     - App.config
     - Program.cs
```

Comment: Is the InnerException null?

Comment: I'm getting a `{Configuration system failed to initialize}` error.

Comment: It may be due to a wrong structure of the config file.

Comment: Can you post all content of your app.config